# HTML5 Video and Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, html, html5-video

I have been trying for the past 2 hours to make HTML5 Video work. Could somebody show me what I am doing wrong? I have a home controller that has ONLY ONE action called `index` which I use to render the home page (index.html.erb). My route file is:

```
TEST::Application.routes.draw do
  get "home/index"

  root :to => 'home#index'

..
..
```

My index.html.erb file has ONLY THIS LINES:

```
<div class="row"> <h3>TEST </h3> </div>

<div class="row">

    <div class="span12">
        <%= video_tag("test_video_1.ogg", :size => "320x240", :controls => true, :autobuffer => true) %>
    </div>


</div>
```

I added this to my "config/application.rb" file:

```
# Enable the asset pipeline
config.assets.enabled = true
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/videos"
```

The stupid video file is there. In "/app/assets/videos". I am using thin server. Now why the buck do I get this error?

```
Started GET "/videos/test_video_1.ogg" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-10-01 13:13:00 +0100

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/videos/test_video_1.ogg"):
```

Could somebody explain me what is happening?

Comment: could you show more of your routes.rb file and also perhaps output from `rake routes` pertaining to the video? It looks like your routing is looking directly at the video file rather than `home#index`. Also, i don't think you need to add `config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/videos"`, in production when you compile assets it should automatically grab everything in this directory anyway. perhaps this is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

It seems `video_tag` looks for stuff under your public folder so you have two options.
Put your video under public/videos and remove the extra path from the assets paths or manually write the video tag pointing to "assets/test_video_1.ogg". (Notice the lack of "videos" here)

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-video_tag